# I want to know why my 'login logic' always false condition?

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean

I want to know why when I make the syntax for the login logic but the password and ID are always wrong? did I do something wrong to my code?
Here's the code

```
public class tester {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Data baru = new Data();

        baru.id.add("HelloGays");
        baru.password.add("hi");
        System.out.println(baru.id.toString());
        System.out.println(baru.password.toString());
        GetCredentials login = new GetCredentials(baru.id,baru.password);
    }
}
```

I initialized the id and password variables as above, then

```
public class Data {
    public ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

that's class for the data collection that i initialized in class Tester

```
public class GetCredentials {

    public GetCredentials(ArrayList id, ArrayList password){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String akses,akses2;
        boolean buffer2=false,kontol=false;
        id = new ArrayList<>();


        System.out.print("Input your ID         :");
        akses = input.nextLine();
        boolean buffer = id.contains(akses);


        password = new ArrayList<>();


        System.out.print("Enter your password   :");

        akses2 = input.nextLine();
        try{
        buffer2 = (password.get(id.indexOf(akses)).equals(akses2));
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            kontol = true;
        }
        if (buffer2==true){
            System.out.println("Succsessful Login");}
        else{
            kontol=true;}

        if (kontol){
            System.err.println("Wrong ID/Password");
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

and above is the syntax for checking login credentials

Comment: Your `password` list is empty, so it will always throw an exception, so `kontol` will always be true, so you will always get the "Wrong password" message. Remove `password = new ArrayList()` in your `GetCredentials` method so you're not overwriting it

Comment: Also, a suggestion - instead of putting your code in the constructor so it'll only be run once, it would be better to have a proper method doing that

Comment: it works, thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `id` and `password` collections are empty.

```
id = new ArrayList<>();
password = new ArrayList<>();
```

These instructions will create new empty collections, so when you try to obtain the password for a user, it will always fail, because there is no single user or password in those collections.